# Creating a Spring MVC Project in Spring Tools 4 (Eclipse)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

1. I installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
2. I went to menu **Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...** and installed "Spring Tools 4 (aka Spring Tools Suite 4)"

My goal is to create a first simple Spring MVC application. So I went to youtube and found a tutorial video. In the video it's proposed to perform the steps **New -> Other... -> Spring** and the following list should appear:

- Import Spring Getting Started Content
- Spring Bean Configuration File
- Spring Bean Definition
- Spring Project
- Spring Roo Project
- Spring Starter Project
- Spring Web Flow Definition File

It's proposed to choose "Spring Project". But I have only two items from that list:

- Import Spring Getting Started Content
- Spring Starter Project

Did I installed anything incorrectly? What am I supposed to choose to create a Spring MVC project (and what options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had trouble with STS 4 and later on I installed 3.9 and it worked just fine.
I recommend you downloading STS if you want to build spring / spring boot projects [ not compulsory though ] .

You can see spring legacy project for spring MVC option and it generates a good project structure which comes with ready to run code and standard project structure.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Download STS - you mean STS 3.9 or what?

Comment: And why spring mvc option is a legacy project? Is spring mvc becoming deprecated or not very popular?

Comment: Yes , download STS 3.9 [3.9.1] . You might see other options for spring for eg spring project / spring legacy project. For spring MVC , if you don't want to create spring boot I think it's still popular. Especially REST APIs are becoming popular nowadays and for that spring boot with spring data jpa is so popular. Depends on what you want to create.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Dynamic web project` and cpnvert that to maven project if you want or can add dependencies in the classpath yourself as jars.

Otherwise You can create a `maven project` and add files like `web.xml` and `spring-mvc-servlet.xml` yourself.

You can use this tutorial for use as this will give you some ideas how to start a spring mvc project in eclipse. https://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and the link! But they don't look like a convenient way to create an empty Spring MVC project, do they? As I understand, the Spring Tools plugin should add Sping projects templates for creating Spring projects in a couple of clicks. For example, I saw a Spring MVC Project template in tutorial videos.

Comment: I don't think there's any preferred way to create a project. I can tell mine we obviously create a project by using Dynamic Web Project things because it provides us the basic structure and let us control all the other required thing however if you want a sample structure created already you can use archtypes in maven projects like https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute

Answer (score 0):

The list of options to create a project that you mentioned from the video is the list of options that you get when using the old Spring Tool Suite 3.

The new Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse have a reduced set of options to create Spring projects and is focused on Spring Boot based projects. In case you start with Spring nowadays, I would strongly recommend to start using Spring Boot and to get started with a Spring Boot project using one of those two options to create a Spring Boot project that comes with the Spring Tools 4.

The old wizards from the Spring Tool Suite 3 (including the Spring MVC project that you could create from it) is not based on Spring Boot and not what I would recommend to start with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you explan the difference between an old Spring MVC Project and a new Spring Boot project? Why should I use the latter?

Comment: The 'legacy' spring mvc projects that STS 3 creates use very old version of Spring that dates back from befor Spring Boot. Spring Boot is a layer on top of Spring that avoids a lot of boilerplate configuration by providing good default 'autoconfiguration'. As such, spring boot is much easier to get started with and quickly create a small toy application. With a 'plain' spring project that would instead require a lot more 'scaffolding' to configure beans that make the application work. For a spring mvc with boot, tutorial, have a look at this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/